# Curve Voting Escrow Explanations

Tags: solidity, defi, voting, escrow, curve

Curve Voting Escrow has gradually become the de facto approach for DeFi projects of gaining, decaying and consuming voting power through the functions on their smart contract. The original contract was written in Vyper and Solidity version was made available by projects like Frax, Reflexer and Workhard Finance etc. as well.

Despite its growing popularity, I have not seen a very well documented technical explanation to their approach in great details. I am wondering if anyone is familar with it and can provide explanations in a layman language. It's going to benefit the whole DeFi community. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to state the questions that you have. As presented the question is very general. The white paper describe the general the mechanism.

Comment: Found a short video on YouTube that did a great job explaining the basic mechanism: https://youtu.be/fKv38FGjA_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Curve DAO whitepaper was very helpful for me for understanding the code, I really recommend starting with it:

https://curve.fi/files/CurveDAO.pdf

Specifically this part:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to Liron's answer, the whitepaper is now moved to https://github.com/curvefi/curve-dao-contracts/blob/master/doc/README.md